# Quarkus Jakarta Persistence

Tags: jpa, quarkus

I found this in the **Quarkus** documentation:

```java
    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Transactional
    public Person update(Long id, Person person) {
        Person entity = Person.findById(id);
        if(entity == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        // map all fields from the person parameter to the existing entity
        entity.name = person.name;

        return entity;
    }
```

Do I need to call `persist()` again on entities already persisted when making changes? Like this:

```java
    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Transactional
    public Person update(Long id, Person person) {
        Person entity = Person.findById(id);
        if(entity == null) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        // map all fields from the person parameter to the existing entity
        entity.name = person.name;

        entity.persist(); // is this needed

        return entity;
    }
```

And also why is the mapping needed? Can't I just call `person.persist()`?

Comment: What is `Person`?  Which documentation are you referencing?

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `persist()` at all. The `Person entity` object is a managed by the persistence context (as a RESULT OF `findById`) and it's state flushed to the database after the transaction is commited as implied by `@Transactional`.

The example code reflects a correct state.

If you call the dto `person.persist()` there are two possible outcomes:

1. `EntityExistsException` thrown assuming the `person` object has id.
2. If the person object id is null, the `person` object will be persistent and you will get a duplicate for your (logical) database entity.